# Linear Regression in R Mapreduce(RHadoop)

Tags: machine-learning, r, apache-hadoop, map-reduce

I m new to RHadoop and also to RMR...
I had an requirement to write a Mapreduce Job in R Mapreduce. I have Tried writing but While executing this it gives an Error.
Tring to read the file from hdfs

### Error:

```
Error in mr(map = map, reduce = reduce, combine = combine, vectorized.reduce,  : 
   hadoop streaming failed with error code 1
```

### Code :

```
Sys.setenv(HADOOP_HOME="/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-4.7.0-1.cdh4.7.0.p0.40/lib/hadoop")
Sys.setenv(HADOOP_CMD="/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-4.7.0-1.cdh4.7.0.p0.40/bin/hadoop")

Sys.setenv(HADOOP_STREAMING="/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-4.7.0-1.cdh4.7.0.p0.40/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming-2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.7.0.jar")
library(rmr2)
library(rhdfs)
hdfs.init()
day_file = hdfs.file("/hdfs/bikes_LR/day.csv","r")
day_read = hdfs.read(day_file)
c = rawToChar(day_read)

XtX =
  values(from.dfs(
    mapreduce(
      input = "/hdfs/bikes_LR/day.csv",
      map=
        function(.,Xi){
         yi =c[Xi[,1],]
         Xi = Xi[,-1]
         keyval(1,list(t(Xi)%*%Xi))
       },
  reduce = function(k,v )
  {
    vals =as.numeric(v)
    keyval(k,sum(vals))
  } ,
  combine = TRUE)))[[1]]

XtY =
 values(from.dfs(
    mapreduce(
     input = "/hdfs/bikes_LR/day.csv",
     map=
       function(.,Xi){
         yi =c[Xi[,1],]
         Xi = Xi[,-1]
        keyval(1,list(t(Xi)%*%yi))
       },
     reduce = TRUE ,
     combine = TRUE)))[[1]]
solve(XtX,XtY)



Input:
------------

instant,dteday,season,yr,mnth,holiday,weekday,workingday,weathersit,temp,atemp,hum,windspeed,casual,registered,cnt
1,2011-01-01,1,0,1,0,6,0,2,0.344167,0.363625,0.805833,0.160446,331,654,985
2,2011-01-02,1,0,1,0,0,0,2,0.363478,0.353739,0.696087,0.248539,131,670,801
3,2011-01-03,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0.196364,0.189405,0.437273,0.248309,120,1229,1349
4,2011-01-04,1,0,1,0,2,1,1,0.2,0.212122,0.590435,0.160296,108,1454,1562
5,2011-01-05,1,0,1,0,3,1,1,0.226957,0.22927,0.436957,0.1869,82,1518,1600
6,2011-01-06,1,0,1,0,4,1,1,0.204348,0.233209,0.518261,0.0895652,88,1518,1606
7,2011-01-07,1,0,1,0,5,1,2,0.196522,0.208839,0.498696,0.168726,148,1362,1510
8,2011-01-08,1,0,1,0,6,0,2,0.165,0.162254,0.535833,0.266804,68,891,959
9,2011-01-09,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0.138333,0.116175,0.434167,0.36195,54,768,822
10,2011-01-10,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0.150833,0.150888,0.482917,0.223267,41,1280,1321



 Please Suggest me any mistakes.
```

Comment: You need to find the log output from your R script, which would indicate the error. "hadoop streaming failed with error code 1" just means "the script failed for some reason"

Comment: Sometimes the folder where you write must be deleted before writing (if it exists). Check that out.

Comment: thank u for ur answer ... but i have check all the possibilites what u have mentioned... i doubt that there is some problem with code itself...can someone please rectify...

Comment: Is this a single machine cluster? Can you provide the stderr log?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using machine learning libraries with already functional linear regression
[Spark MLlib](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.1.0/mllib-guide.html) or [hivemall](https://github.com/myui/hivemall).

Comment: These don't relate to R or MapReduce, which seem to be requirements here.

Comment: On spark You can write in python. Use RPy library for integrating R an Python.